# Class on validation message is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Normally I would write code like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
```

Where UserName is a required property of the model.  This would show whatever message I have configured.  This works, but in a particular case I'm working on, the HTML that gets generated does not have a class attribute set.  Normally it gets set to:

```
class="error"
```

But the code I'm seeing generated in this project is:

```
class=""
```

So the text the user sees is just plain text.  Not decorated (red) by my CSS for .error.

Any ideas why the class name is not being output to the HTML?

Comment: Can you post the code for what you have now, rather than what you usually have?

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing.  That's pretty much the code.  I'm just not understanding why the class name is not set.  I must be missing something and no idea what to go look for.